# Magento contact us email not working

Tags: php, email, magento, smtp

`Send mail` functionality is not working in `Magento 1.9.0.1`. While click send button in `Contact us` form **Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later** exception is showing.

I am using `SMTP pro plugin` downloaded from [**here**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html). In `var/log/exception.log` shows:

```
2015-05-07T12:44:30+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsGp
 5.7.14 XNjb7oIlM9RB1iZFx_Kt1PVznMaSpGsNvG76lmw3nf2-qyt_fO5wqJ3YErRCVHVIEO8QIq
 5.7.14 4B43ekmCa2WCiNMtPb2aMfODWntmPm6_LipTs1iXK5-lPx2mtx0Lzg3IKq7iZMsJ6Gowh1
 5.7.14 XO6qB_OQFszKTl8a0mE3CkzTXhss8Qmu8dLz96NZhxKkyMM50B-gg11g6CZzYPBeOWQQe1
 5.7.14 oUeBqf-Xo7YzplmPqbuFfx4Sn9_E> Please log in via your web browser and
 5.7.14 then try again.
 5.7.14 Learn more at
 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 b10sm2160560pdj.0 - gsmtp
' in D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
#1 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\lib\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\lib\Zend\Mail\Transport\Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\lib\Zend\Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\local\Aschroder\SMTPPro\Model\Email\Template.php(132): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php(506): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send('santhoshthittay...', NULL, Array)
#7 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php(104): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('contacts_email_...', 'general', 'santhoshthittay...', NULL, Array)
#8 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Contacts_IndexController->postAction()
#9 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#10 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\td\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

**EDIT:**

I used `Google apps or gmail` for the `Email Connection` in `SMTP Pro settings`.

Comment: Looks to me like it’s not accepting your login. Did you turn on 2FA?